# MongoDb C# driver slow for first query after app start

Tags: c#, performance, mongodb, driver, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm testing out MongoDB (3.0) using C# driver and I noticed something strange.

I started test db localy and then I created testing console application. In there, I do this to initialize the driver:

```
var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
```

So far so good, but then I tried to get data based on id (indexed by default), so I added this:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("myData");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("id", "F1234");
var result = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result;
```

To get average time consumption I added code to measure time for the query (by decorating it with two DateTime.Now and then substracting them - i know, dirty) and put all the code in the loop. Also, I let each iteration time display on console

Now everytime I hit F5, first iteration takes about 150ms, but next iterations are about 1ms on average. Important is, that this has nothing to do with cache, because each iteration can query for different id and the result is exactly the same. Also, I can initialize the MongoClient again with each iteration, but it always behaves as I described.

Each first query after app start takes more time.

I need to know, if this is really due some initialization inside MongoClient (maybe some static classes are initializec with first query?), or if this can happen anytime while running the app.

***Note***:
I also tried to replace the query by Thread.Sleep just to be sure it is not some .NET issue. And it is not. It is really the "collection.Find" which takes more time with first usage.

Thank you!

***Note after some time***

So after some time, I found out that each CRUD operation needs its "warm-up-first-request". Sometimes each CRUD operation on each collection. Strange. I'm posting this to let others know :-)

Comment: Use `Stopwatch` when benchmarking not `DateTime.Now`.  As for the slowness it could be the JIT.

Comment: Still the same result..

Comment: @MartinPotvrzenejBrabec Do you actually have any data in that collection?

Comment: Yes, I have. More than 400k records.

Comment: @MartinPotvrzenejBrabec Do you shut down the db between each test, or leave it up?

Comment: @MartinPotvrzenejBrabec btw, you should tag people to notify them when you address them.

Comment: @i3arnon I will tag people from now on :-) No, the db itself is still running and also the connection is still the same. I will do some tests yet, but it looks like this really only happens with first query only.

Comment: @MartinPotvrzenejBrabec, When benchmarking, there should always be a warm-up period. If you are talking about why the first one is slower, there could be many reasons. The initial reason would be that we have to open a connection which isn't free. As far as whether this can happen anytime, it absolutely can for many, many reasons. There is a network involved, and anything can happen out on that network.